# How to make prediction with single sample in sklearn model.predict?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I trained a logistic regression model with some data.
I applied standard scalar to train and test data, trained model.
But if I want to make prediction with the model with the data outside the train and test data, I have to apply standard scalar to new data but what if I have single data than i cannot apply standard scalar to that new single sample that i want to give as input.
What should be the procedure to predict results with new data especially single sample at a time?

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code along with the error or expected results.

Answer (score 7):

The `predict()` method always expects a 2D array of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`. This means that if you want to predict even for a single data point, you will have to convert it into a 2D array.

Converting data into a 2D array using reshape

```py
# Sample data
print(arr)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

# Reshaping into 2D
arr.reshape(1, -1)

# Result
array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

This array can now be transformed using standard scalar using `transform()` method before being used to generate a prediction from the model.

Comment: After applying standard scalar to the reshaped array every element becomes zero.

Comment: You sould `fit()` or `fit_transform()` on the training data only. For your testing data and the single sample only use the `transform()` mtehod.

Comment: Are there any downsides of predicting on sample vs several at a time?